# Can't get the input right

Tags: c

I want to get an input from the user, skipping spaces but for some reason this code seems not to work!

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #define  MAX 50

 char *gettline();

 int main()
 {
     char *input;
     for( ; ; )
     {/*here i try to check the input and output*/
         printf("#");
         input = gettline();
         printf("%s\n",input);
         free(input);     
      }
    return 0;
 }


char *gettline(){
  int c,i;
  char *input = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);

  while((input[0]=c=getchar())==' ' || c=='\t'))
       ;
  input[1]='\0';

  i=0;
  while((c=getchar()) != EOF || c!='\n')
  input[i++] = c;

  input[i]='\0';
  return input;
  }
```

the output prints '#' and gets my string, however,
the output wont print the string from the input for some reason...
any help will be great!
thanks in advance

Comment: As style matter, I'd point out that the `continue` in the main is not needed.

I'd encourage you to rewrite `getline()` as a `repeat` loop (until input is EOF or newline or max is reached) which gets a character and if it's not blank or tab adds it to `input`.  I think you will find that does what you intend much more clearly.

Comment: @ChrisNelson Im trying over and over and over again!! for the like 100 time...... nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classical mistake in C.

```
while((input[0]=c=getchar())==' ' || (input[0]=c='\t'))
```

The last `=` should be `==`.

There's a second problem, too (as you discovered while I was working on it).

```
while((c=getchar()) != EOF || c!='\n')
```

The `||` should be `&&`.

One more thing: you're losing your first character because of your logic. I'll leave that to you to solve. :-)

Comment: thank you very much! the problem I didn't sleep tonight, as i had to write this (this is only a small bit of it) work for my class in C, and I missed the && somehow :( i couldnt find the problem for more than 5 hours, thanks you again

Comment: also yes, the fgetc() is just a tool i tried to use while debuging

Comment: `fgetc()`? I don't see that anywhere.

Anyway, I came back to suggest you consider avoiding assignments in boolean expressions. It's one of those C "features" that has over the years wasted productivity with needless bugs that are hard to detect, especially because it's so easy for the eye to see what it wants to see, rather than what's actually there. It's such a bad idea that most languages forbid it, and even C++ compilers these days warn you about it. In the long run it's almost certainly a better idea to rewrite it so that the assignment takes place outside the boolean expression.

Comment: I deleted it from here,it was bad mistake, anyway tank you for your time and advices! I will shurly imply them